# MovingAverage to include the average of the first and last elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there any way to take the average of pairwise elements in a list?

Example: Given the list

```
list = {a,b,c}
```

I'd like to generate the list

```
{(a+b)/2, (b+c)/2, (a+c)/2}
```

In this case, `MovingAverage` almost does the job with the exception of averaging `a` and `c`. Adding `a` at the end of `list` does the job, but what if I absolutely have to preserve the contents of `list`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
list = {a, b, c};
Append[MovingAverage[list, 2], Mean[{First[list], Last[list]}]]
```

> ```
> {(a+b)/2, (b+c)/2, (a+c)/2}
> ```

You can define a function if you want:

```
newMovingAverage[list_] := Append[MovingAverage[list, 2], Mean[{First[list], Last[list]}]]

newMovingAverage[list]
```

> ```
> {(a+b)/2, (b+c)/2, (a+c)/2}
> ```

Comment: Ah nice, that was fast! Thanks to both answers!

Comment: @user170231 Glad I could help! Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 15):

```
list = {a, b, c};

Mean[{#, RotateLeft@#}]& @ list
Mean /@ Partition[#, 2, 1 , 1]& @ list
Developer`PartitionMap[Mean, #, 2, 1, 1]& @ list
MovingAverage[ArrayPad[#, {0, 1}, "Periodic"], 2]& @ list
MovingAverage[PadRight[#, 1 + Length@#, #], 2]& @list
({##} + { ##2, #})/2 & @@ list
```

> ```
> {(a + b)/2, (b + c)/2, (a + c)/2}
> ```

#### Perfomance Comparison

```
sol1 = Mean[{#, RotateLeft@#}] &;
sol2 = Mean /@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] &;
sol3 = Developer`PartitionMap[Mean, #, 2, 1, 1] &;
sol4 = MovingAverage[ArrayPad[#, {0, 1}, "Periodic"], 2] &;
sol5 = MovingAverage[PadRight[#, 1 + Length@#, #], 2] &;
sol6 = .5 ({##} + {##2, #}) & @@ # &;
RunnyKine = .5 ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, #, 1] &;
Ivan = Append[MovingAverage[#, 2], Mean[{First[#], Last[#]}]] &;

timing[func_, n_] :=
  First@(AbsoluteTiming[func[RandomReal[{1, 10}, 10^n]]])
```

***Test***

```
Table[timing[func, #] & /@ 
  Range[7], {func, {sol1, sol2, sol3, sol4, sol5, sol6, RunnyKine,Ivan}}];

ListLinePlot[%, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 12}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"n", "time"}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"sol1", "sol2", "sol3", "sol4", "sol5", "sol6", 
   "RunnyKine","Ivan"}
]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 13):

One can also use `ListCorrelate` or `ListConvolve` which I expect to be quick:

```
1/2 ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, list, 1]
```

Gives:

> {(a + b)/2, (b + c)/2, (a + c)/2}

Comment: That's the way to do it if speed is needed....+1

Comment: Why not have the kernel be `{1, 1}/2` to begin with?

Comment: @J. M. That was my initial kernel, I tried the current one for speed gains but noticed there weren't any. I just decided this one looked cleaner to me.

Answer (score 7):

This seems pretty speedy:

```
With[{l = Divide[#, 2]}, Append[Most@l + Rest@l, Plus @@ l[[{1, -1}]]]] &
```

Comment: Nicely done and quite speedy.